# including header file in a separate folder

Tags: c++, makefile, qmake, nmake

I created a class (say, myclass.h/cpp).  I want to use the class from many different places. Therefore, I put those files in a folder (say, C:\cpp_include) and I want to include them from whatever folder my codes are.  I have a code which uses the class (say, main.cpp). In main.cpp, I include myclass:

```
#include "myclass.h"
```

I compile using a .pro file and nmake. In the .pro file, I specify the folder as:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\cpp_include
```

When I compile the code using nmake, myclass.h is properly included, but myclass.cpp doesn't seem to be found by compiler.
When I specify myclass.cpp as one of the source files in .pro file:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp C:\cpp_include\myclass.cpp
```

The exe file is built correctly. But, I would like myclass.cpp file to be found automatically when myclass.h is included, i.e. without setting myclass.cpp as a source file. Would this be possible? It looks like that's what happens with classes from Qt and Qwt (e.g .h/cpp files in /src/ folder in Qt and Qwt). Am I missing somthing?

Thanks a lot!

Daisuke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple technique is to have build scripts (makefiles) in the `cpp` directories.  Write a rule that traverses the directories, executing the build scripts.  This one step in isolating functionality and also allows one to use libraries.

Answer (score 0):

That's just not how it works. The .cpp is *the* file that matters, header files (.h) just get copied into the other .cpp files. Therefore you need to add the myclass.cpp to your sources for compiling. Or, if it's a library class, you could also compile it once into a static library (.lib) and just add that to your linker files. But you ultimately need to somehow include you implementation in the project where it's used.